# Joining tables results in null values within joined part using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, table, null

I have tried various geoprocessing tools, read through the stack exchange, googled questions, and I still have not figured this out.

I am trying to join a table based on GEOID field. I made sure both tables have the same text data types, same field name, and same data type length. However, every time I try to join the table it results in null values. I am not sure what is causing this.

**Table 1:**
[image]

**Table 2:**
[image: Table 2]

**What the join looks like:**
[image]

Comment: Table definitions don't tell the tale as much as table contents. Since table1 permits NULL values, there's every reason to believe a NULL would be correct on join.

Comment: @Vince I'd agree but the table I am joining has no Null variables. I've uploaded another picture showing what the table looks like after a join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your GEOID columns has a leading zero, so that's why they are not joining, you are joining on text fields so the text don't match up. You have two options: convert the GEOID fields to numeric format or add a leading zero to the GEOID field that is missing it.

You probably want to do the latter as leading zero's usually hold some importance in census datasets.